# How do I compress the size of Electron App

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

So recently I make a simple app using Electron, it didn't do much but it takes **153 mb** of storage (which is big). Is there any way to compress it?

Comment: Your code is a very small part of the full app. It has  standalone full browser and  node server

Comment: are you pruning it (prune option in electron packager)?